# What is the size of FLOAT in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I found one reference which said it was a double, and one that said Decimal, but no indication of the size.

64 bits?  128 bits?

This (obviously) affect the value range and precision that can be stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IEEE 754 Double-precision floating point. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format